# vibrantLinux | Cant start

Tags: amd-graphics

I have Ubuntu 23.04 and Amd Radeon RX570 (8 Gigabyte edition). I want to change color saturation. For this I use vibrantLinux (FlatPak version). When I run the program I get an error:

```
Gtk-Message: 18:52:33.501: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 18:52:33.502: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Qt: Session management error: Could not open network socket
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  this system has no supported displays
```

Who knows what's the problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I use X11 version